# How did I become Evil General Manager?

Tags: dont-get-fired

When I was playing the game, my character was in DGM (deputy general manager if I'm not mistaken) position.

Suddenly, out of nowhere, when the xp points were not even full, the promotion screen came up and I was informed that I received a promotion for Evil General Manager.

What are the requirements to become an evil GM? Can I become an angel GM?
Are GM's and Director's the only positions where you can become an angel or evil?

I have searched for that subject and I only found a video of an [Angel Director](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2aIjASb2hI).

Comment: Are you sure that it promotes you to the next position? I thought that it kept you at the same position, but now I'm starting to doubt my memory. haha

Comment: I'm quite sure! The XP was not even in the middle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evil promotion has a chance to happen after picking a 'mean' option to your subordinates.

Likewise the angel promotion has a chance to happen after picking a 'nice' option to your subordinates.

Any managerial position can become an Angel or Evil as you need to respond to a subordinate event in order to acquire it.

Remember that like all other hidden positions, being promoted to the next position will cause you to lose your hidden position, so it may be a good idea to get fired on purpose for the extra money.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get evil manager or angel director is to either pick constant mean answers for evil or constant nice answers for angel. When becoming the evil deputy manager you get double the pension and +10% promotion chance while at that position. As angel you lose 10% promotion chance but still get double the pension.